# SQL-Server: Summing a column while ignoring duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, duplicates, distinct

I have a table that contains rows with duplicated values.

```
TransID--CustID-- Date-----Amount
5217151 212671  2020-10-31  30.00
5217151 212671  2020-10-31  30.00
5219330 212671  2020-11-30  30.00
5219330 212671  2020-11-30  30.00
```

I need to sum the Amount column, but ignore any rows where the transaction ID is duplicated. For example, the sum of Amount for customer 212671 would be 60.00. I have tried to use Select Distinct but I cannot figure out the correct syntax for doing this when using distinct on one column but summing on a different one.

This is my first post on stackoverflow and I'm finding it very difficult to format my text and paste in actual screen shots of the data, so please excuse that. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicated values sound like something's wrong in your DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply DISTINCT before aggregation:

```
with cte as
 (
   select distinct TransID, CustID, Amount
   from mytable
 )
select CustId, sum(Amount)
from cte
group by CustId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of aggregation or aggregation with a window function:

```
select custid, sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by custid, transid order by transid) as seqnum
      from table_1 t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Assuming my table name is table_1 is this the correct syntax?

select custid, sum(amount)
from (select table_1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by custid, transid order by transid) as seqnum
      from table_1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;

I get the following error 

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Column 't.custid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.